# Running python script in ABAQUS UMAT

Tags: fortran, abaqus

I want to call a python script which uses libraries that require python version greater than 3. The problem is that the default python used by ABAQUS is python2.7.

I tried this in a Fortran subroutine, where my.py is a script that uses pytorch lightning

```
  CALL SYSTEM("python -m my.py > output.txt")
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
  File "/opt/Simulia/EstProducts/2020/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Which version of Python is the `python` command? Which versions do you have installed? Where? Under which commands are they accessible? Do you have a `python3` command available? How does your script look like?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I have python 2.7.5 under /usr/bin/python and python 3.6.8 in /usr/bin/python3

To test, I am only using a simple script with print("hello")

Comment: If I write CALL SYSTEM("python3 -V >output.txt") in fortran, it runs and it gives Python 3.6.8. If I replace -V with my.py, it yields the error

Comment: What kind of error? The same as before or different?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава The same

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I’m working on multiscale analysis and I’m trying to call a Python script inside UMAT.
I think it’s barely impossible to run another version of Python than 2.7
It’s been quite a while that I’m trying to find a hack somewhere but there is a lot of dependencies with this version.
As an Abaqus user, if you try to modify, update or install a new module or a new version of Python :

- either Abaqus will stop working
- the module won’t be imported because there is a path problem or some version dependency.

So my advice is to find another software
or to wait for the update to the version 3.7 on 2024.

Good luck !